# Twitter 1.1 API , asking for request token, sends me to URL showing PIN

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

1) Asking for request token, sends me to URL showing PIN.

2) Then i use this PIN to get the access token.

3) This access token is used by my function :

```
   statuses_userTimeline( <user id number>, <access token> )
```

My question,

1) would i need to get the PIN everytime ?

2) Is pin not accessible in a call back function. ( As it seems twitter especially shows it as image file, that must be entered manually )

3) Is their a way to get access token, by using authorization URL only. ( and not using the PIN ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer.
The PIN is required only once, after then, the content can be accessed without PIN, using the access token.